# regarding graphical user interfaces in c on linux operating system

Tags: linux

I want to know whether we need to download GTK for making graphical interfaces in C on linux, since i have read somewhere that it is by default installed.

Answer (score 1):

There exist a lot of library to do GUI in linux. Some are installed by default depending on the Distribution and your environment (eg: gnome come with GTK).

You can also want to use other library <strike>like qt</strike>... (with may required an installation if it is not provided in your distribution, but nowadays, It is really easy to install such library eg: apt-get, yum, rpm...)

Comment: Note that if you distribute your software as a package, you simply have to make the package depend on the GTK+ package. If it's not already installed, the package manager will install it along with whatever other dependencies are needed.

Answer (score 1):

You have a number of choices for a GUI on Linux. Most distros ship with x11 at least, though you will have to design the controls yourself. GTK and QT are two common toolkits, which have their own look and feel (of course QT isn't C).